# What does "work on my tan" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Here is the context:

He

> It's not gonna be easy

She

> Well, I don't do easy. If I wanted that I'd move to Florida and work on my tan

Comment: To "work on one's tan" means to do something trivial, more like rest than actual work. Often it simply means one intends to idle.

Comment: The more literal meaning is to sunbathe to get a darker skin.

Comment: To chill or goof-off. Hard to cite though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work on in this sense in the literal sense means that they are going to try and become more tan.

You could say:
"I am going to work on my car" in this case, it would mean to fix/repair
"I am going to work on my thesis" in this case, it would mean that they are working towards the completion of their thesis.

There is a lot going on in this. If you look at the entire text, I would say that the root meaning of the last sentence would just be a declaration/example of something that is easy to do(since tanning is simply laying in the sun).